# Finding the pixel values corresponding to each intensity peaks

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I have an interference fringe pattern. I applied Fourier transform on it which gave an image with few very sharp peaks corresponding to each spatial frequency. My question is that is there any way(algorithm) to detect coordinates(pixel value) corresponding to these intense peaks?

Please note that there are more than one peaks(but not many) with different magnitudes.

Comment: well you might set a threshold and use find(Matrix>threshold) would give you indices of the locations greater than the thresold

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the built-in [`findpeaks`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/findpeaks.html), for example:

```
 [pks,locs] = findpeaks(data)
```

returns local maxima or peaks, `pks`, in the input data, with the indices of the local peaks `locs`. The input `data` requires a row or column vector with real-valued elements with a minimum length of three. `findpeaks` compares each element of data to its neighboring values. If an element of data is larger than both of its neighbors or equals Inf, the element is a local peak. If there are no local maxima, `pks` will be an empty vector.

To set a threshold use any of the following handles: `'MINPEAKHEIGHT'` , `'MINPEAKDISTANCE'`, or , `'THRESHOLD'`

for example:

```
[pks,locs] = findpeaks(data,'MINPEAKHEIGHT',10)
```